# Wrong result with basic formula (Add and subtraction) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My sheets have random wrong results with basic add and subtraction formulas. I can correct by replacing the exactly same formula from another sheet but it makes the calculation unreliable.

The formula: =E218+G218-H218-F218 which should return 0 but it returned -39 insteads.

I removed all importrange posible causes by Copy value of all imported ranges. I also removed protection, unnecessary sheets and unrelated ranges, named it 'Basic version'.

This is one of wrong result cell, and it happens randomly.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jPbSJU0iyn6LjuRRwjc5x7Hy7sLL8CxmiXa7pdXXqEA/edit#gid=265206709&range=I218

Feel free to edit, I made a copy of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your provided sheet showing `0`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question. What is the issue, where, and what steps will get us to the same result you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

delete column `I` and use this in row 2:

```
=INDEX({"Số lượng bán trong ca"; E3:E+G3:G-H3:H-F3:F})
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks alot. I belive I caused by my messy formula